# C++ Stack Walking on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, stack, callstack

I'm building a memory manager for C++ using a very .NET style approach. In doing so I need to know which objects are considered reachable; and object is considered reachable if a reachable object has a handle to the object in question. So this poses the question of which object(s) are the root of our search? The answer would be that these "eve" objects are on the stack, be it in the form of a handle to a managed object or an instance of a scope-local object that itself has a handle to a managed object.

I've read through some articles on this and also checked out implementation details on the MSDN about the StackWalk method in the Win32 API.

As always any help is greatly appreciated. And please don't advise against making a memory manager, or suggest alternatives such as smart pointers. I fully understand what I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need it to be precise, or approximate? Because precise is probably impossible unless you customize your compiler.

Comment: Remember the stacks of other threads, objects (with callbacks) held by the OS...

Comment: Also when walking the stack you don't know the type of the variables you meet. They could be INTs, they could be pointers, they could well be a part of a larger class or struct ...

Comment: The same memory cell of the same stack frame could mean different things based on the block you're in (space reuse); it's not defined by the function (entry point).

Comment: @JanDvorak: I think an easy way to summarize all these problems is to say "it's impossible to do correctly without compiler help". (Which doesn't imply it's very possible to do it even with compiler help, but that's another issue...) :P

Comment: This is not possible unless you tell your compiler to mark stack entries for objects as objects. What you find on the stack could be an object pointer, an int, a long, a char*, etc.

Comment: "I fully understand what I am doing." Are you sure?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I understand that stack frame entries are not symbolic and that I won't be able to identify internal data types. I already have logic for identifying arbitrary objects out of spaces of memory. So no, it does not need to be very precise.

Comment: Get some help from your user?  `GCObject<T,Stack>` that simply forwards constructor to `T`, vs `GCObject<T,Owned>` that takes an `Owner` ptr as arg1, then forwards constructors to `T`?  Or even `Stack<T>` vs `Heap<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements sort of seem similar to a small project I’m working on at the moment, but my goal isn’t to make a memory manager, my goal is to instrument dmalloc (and the debug-mode long-running application within which it is running) with the ability to periodically halt execution and scan memory looking for heap allocations for which there are no references.  Sort of like a “dumb” garbage collector, but not with the goal of freeing memory; instead, with the goal of logging leaked allocations for later analysis (along with stacktraces captured at allocation-time, which I’ve already added to dmalloc).  Note that as a general-purpose memory manager’s garbage collector, this will be a pretty inefficient process and will take a “long” time to run (I’m not done yet, but I won’t be surprised if each time it runs it halts normal program execution for over 10 seconds), but for my own purposes I don’t care too much about performance because I’ll enable it only once every few months to test for new memory leaks in my company’s product.

In any case, I assume your memory manager will be the only source of heap memory in your application?  And that threads in your system operate in a fully shared-memory environment, where no thread has any memory, including stack space and thread-local storage space, that cannot be seen from other threads?  If so...

I believe there are just four categories of memory within which you may find pointers to heap allocations:

1. On the callstacks of each thread
2. Within heap allocations themselves
3. In statically allocated writable memory (.bss & .data/.sdata, but
   not .rdata/.rodata)
4. In thread-local storage space for each thread

You are already aware that pointers to heap allocations may occur on the stack.  Pointers to allocations may also (may *instead*) be stored in heap objects themselves, and not even stored on the stack.  Your question suggests you may be hoping to use the stack as a “root” of your garbage collector’s search; I’m taking this to mean you hope to be able to follow pointers on the stack outwards to other allocations, searching from one object to another through memory until you’ve traversed all objects in memory and found all pointers to all allocations.  "Root" pointers may also exist in statically allocated objects, which can be referenced directly without there even being a pointer to such an object on the stack, so you can't just assume all allocations are reachable from "pointers" you find in the stack.  Also, unfortunately with C++, unless you’re able to know the structure of each allocation (which you won’t without help from the compiler), you’ll have to assume that any location is possibly a pointer.  So you’ll have to scan through each of these four categories of memory looking for potential pointers to all existing allocations, flagging each with a “possibly still in use” flag if you find a value in memory that matches the address of an allocation, whether or not it’s actually a pointer.  As you scan through memory, at each byte location (or at each byte location evenly divisible by sizeof(void*), if you know your platform can’t have pointers at misaligned addresses), you’ll have to search your list of allocations to see if that value is in your list of allocations.

Since you're confident that you know what you’re doing, your memory manager is probably tracking these allocations in a balanced tree structure (perhaps a red-black tree or Andersson tree) which gives you O(log n) insertion & lookup on those allocations, but the constant of proportionality for navigating those trees is going to really kill your garbage collector’s performance.  Before doing your garbage collection scan, you’ll want to copy the tree’s allocation pointers into a flat contiguous buffer (i.e. an “array”) in order (i.e. ascending or descending using inorder traversal).  I suggest an array of `void*` of each allocation’s address and a separate bit-array (not `bool` array) with one bit per allocation, initialized to all-zeros, where an allocation’s corresponding bit is set to 1 if you find a potential reference to it.  This will still give you O(log n) lookup (using binary search) while you’re scanning for garbage collection, but with a much more manageable constant of proportionality for your lookups; in addition, this more compact data structure will tend to have better cache hit performance than a balanced tree.

Now I’ll discuss each of the three categories of memory you’d have to scan:

- The callstacks of each thread

For this, you’ll have to be able to query your thread manager for the top & bottom of each thread’s stacks.  If you can only get the current stack pointer for each thread, then you may be able to use a “backtrace” API to get a list of function return addresses on that stack.  From that, you can scan back toward each stack’s base (which you don’t know), ticking off each return address in order until you get to the last return address, where you’ve then found the stack base (or close enough).  And for the “current thread”, be sure to not include any stackframes associated with your memory manager; i.e., back up a few stackframes & ignore the ones associated with your garbage collector, or else you might find addresses of leaked allocations in your garbage collector’s local variables and mistake them for

- Within heap allocations themselves

Heap objects can reference each other, and you could have a network of leaked objects that all reference each other yet as a group, they are leaked.  You don't want to see their pointers to each other & treat them as "in-use", so you have to handle these carefully... and last.  Once all other categories are finished, you can collapse/split your flat array of `void*` allocation addresses, making a separate list of "considered in-use" allocations and "not yet verified" allocations.  Scan through the "considered in-use" allocations looking for potential pointers to allocations still in the "not yet verified" list.  As you find any, move them from the "not yet verified" list to the end of the "considered in-use" list so that you'll eventually scan those as well.

- In statically allocated writable memory (.bss & .data/.sdata, but not
  .rdata/.rodata)

For this, you’ll need to get symbols from your linker to the start & end (or length) of each of these sections.  If such symbols don’t already exist or you can’t get that information from a platform API, you’ll need to get your linker command script (linker script) and modify it to add & initialize global symbols to the start address & end address (or length) of each of these sections.  The .bss section contains uninitialized global, file scope, and class static data members.  The .data/.sdata section(s) contain non-const pre-initialized global, file scope, and class static data members.  You don’t need to worry about the .rdata/.rodata section(s) because your program won’t be writing heap-allocation addresses into static const data.

- In thread-local storage space for each thread

For this, you’ll have to be able to query your thread manager for the thread-local storage space for each thread, or else part of the startup of each thread must be to add its thread-local storage to a list of thread-local space for the application, and remove it when the thread exits.

---

If you’re still on board and want to do this, by now you’ve probably realized it’s a bigger project than you may have initially thought.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: If you are doing collection (rather than leak detection) then you have to watch out for interior pointers and pointers stored in locations external to the application memory space. For example, a pointer passed as the parameter to a posted message is not visible to the application while it is in the message queue, but you don't want to collect it until the message is processed.

Comment: @RaymondChen - Ouch!  Hadn't thought about multiple-derivation derived class pointers not pointing to the allocation's base address.  That surely does throw a monkey-wrench into the mess.  Now we're back to needing compiler support for the garbage collector, it seems.

Comment: I have to say this response is excellent in its quality and breadth of information; thank you. As time goes on I teeter totter with the two thoughts: "This is way too difficult and just really not worth the trouble, considering the fragility." and "I've learned a lot about this since the last time I tried it so let's give it a go again." Your response confirms that to build a truly robust, efficient, and comprehensive memory manager I may need to do some more reading. Thanks again. Upvote!

Comment: I should also mention that our immediate need for the leak detector I described above evaporated when we found the cause of our mysterious approx. 1GB "leak", or in our case, allocation anomaly... caused within dmalloc itself when we made our 4,294,967,296th allocation.  After that, dmalloc started failing sanity-checks that assume that the `sa_seen_c / 2` counter never exceeds `_dmalloc_iter_c`.  When _dmalloc_iter_c wraps back to zero, every `free()` of an allocation that was made prior to the rollover triggers a sanity-check failure log message, filling the in-memory log buffer... a lot.

Comment: @WilliamCustode - WOW... This web page describes an apparently already-implemented version of EXACTLY what we're discussing here:  http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/     ...and they're claiming it's at least reasonably performant.